# WPF floating listbox

Tags: wpf, layout

I have a textbox that I would like to combine with a listbox in such a way that when the user types into the textbox, certain items will appear in the listbox, and the user may select them from there.  What I am looking for is behaviour similar to that of the AutoCompleteBox.  Sadly, I can't use the existing AutocompleBox in my project for several reasons, so I am trying to come up with similar behaviour on my own.  Any ideas?

EDIT:
I would like to avoid using the tooltip as this seems like a hack.  Also, when the listbox is displayed, no layouts should be changed either in the control or elsewhere.   Is there something like the CSS style overflow available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it looks like "Popup" is what I am looking for.  It's got some of its own quirks, but so far it is working just fine.  I am pretty much using it like this..

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>

    <Popup Name="popOptions" Width="300" Height="100" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="False">
      <ItemsControl ClipToBounds="False" Background="White" MouseLeftButtonUp="ItemsControl_MouseLeftButtonUp">
        <sys:String>ITEM ONE</sys:String>
        <sys:String>ITEM TWO</sys:String>
        <sys:String>ITEM THREE</sys:String>
      </ItemsControl>
    </Popup>
</DockPanel>
```

I am capturing other control events to decide when, and when not to display it.

Comment: Something to keep in mind about a Popup is that it stays on top of everything, even other applications, and it doesn't move with your application if you move it around.

Comment: This problem is mitigated by setting the 'StaysOpen' flag to false.  I edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the ListBox in the TextBox's ToolTip

I'm not sure if that's the best way of doing what you're trying to accomplish, but it will work to make a floating listbox

Comment: yeah, but then I can't use the tooltip for anything else.  I will probably go this route if nothing else is possible.

Comment: The ToolTip can include other controls than just the ListBox... for example it could hold a TextBlock containing the regular tooltip and a ListBox.

Comment: I wonder if its possible to nest ToolTips - Have a ToolTip on a control inside a ToolTip. I'll have to try it someday

Comment: yes, I have done some pretty exciting tooltipping in my day, but I am still trying to avoid this if at all possible.  It doesn't seem like the correct approach.